# Execute a scheduled lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have an AWS Python lambda function that connects to a DB, checks data integrity and send alerts to a slack channel(that's already done).

I want to execute that lambda every XX minutes.

What's the best way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build this with [AWS EventBridge](https://aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/).

The documentation contains an example for this exact use case:

[Tutorial: Schedule AWS Lambda Functions Using EventBridge](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/run-lambda-schedule.html)